# Write data Firebase Swift $

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swift4

I need to write data like this struct

[image]

the error is this

[image]

I already try with this syntax but I get an error, I have the feeling that it is a small error but I can not find it.

```
                    self.ref.child("Users").child(userID).setValue([
                    "DatosPersonales" : {
                        "ID" : userID,
                        "email" : userEmail,
                        "password" : userPass,
                        "Nombre" : userName,
                        "ImagenProfiel" : "0",
                        },
                    "Progreso" : {
                        "Nivel" : "0",
                        "LugaresVisitados" : { "idLugar" : "0",}
                    }

                    ])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're passing a JSON object to it, not dictionary. Try editing your data like this:

```
self.ref.child("Users").child(userID).setValue([
    "DatosPersonales" : [
        "ID" : userID,
        "email" : userEmail,
        "password" : userPass,
        "Nombre" : userName,
        "ImagenProfiel" : "0",
    ],
    "Progreso" : [
        "Nivel" : "0",
        "LugaresVisitados" : ["idLugar" : "0"]
    ]
])
```

Replace all the curly brackets with square brackets

Comment: Please be a good buddy and accept the answer if it's correct. Or maybe even upvote it if you like it. Thank you :)